# Two custom multiselect drop down dependent on each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

Two custom multiselect drop down dependent on each other and based on combined result need to show items and when selecting one then in other dropdown value should be disabled if combination is not found

```
<div class="firstdrop">
    <span value="ss">ss</span>
    <span value="dd">dd</span>
</div>
<div class="seconddrop">
    <span value="game">game</span>
    <span value="football">football</span>
</div>
<div class="game ss"></div>
<div class="gamee dd"></div>
<div class="football ss"></div>
<div class="ss"></div>
```

Comment: So what is the question ? What is the input data ? How does your script look like ?

Comment: question--how to achieve this?
input data--- checkbox in dropdown for multiple select and below div need to be filtered..

Comment: — How about other questions I asked ?

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done this in the past (loosely based on your example):

```
if($('#firstdrop').val() == 'some value') {
    var oldval = $('#seconddrop').val();  // In case the chosen option exists in the new option set
    var opts = '<option value="val1">Val 1</option>';
    opts += '<option value="val2">Val 2</option>'; 
    etc...
    $('#seconddrop').empty().append(opts).val(oldval);
}
```

Oh, and you need to use select tags, not divs.

```
<select multiple id="firstdrop">...
<select multiple id="seconddrop">...
```